# react boostrap5 rightside shoulod be fixed top right

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-5

I tried so many times but with no success.

the Rightside component was out of the container.
I need the Rightside being sticky or fixed on the right side top below my header. And its width should be the same as col-md-4.

[my app looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xf8F7.png)

Belows are my codes:

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import Header from './components/Header';
import Leftside from './components/Leftside';
import Rightside from './components/Rightside';
import Middle from './components/Middle';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      
      <Header />

      <div className='container pt-5 mt-5'>
        <div className='row'>
          <div className='col-md-2'>
            <div className='container' >
            <Leftside />
            </div>
          
          </div>
          <div className='col-md-6'>
          <div className='container' >
            <Middle />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className='col-md-4'>
          <div className='container' >
            <Rightside />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    
  );
}



export default App;
```

Header.jsx

```
import React from 'react'

const Header = () => {
  return (
    
      <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-top  ">


          <div className="container ">
              <a className="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
              <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarColor03" aria-controls="navbarColor03" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                  <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
              </button>
              <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarColor03">
                  <ul className="navbar-nav me-auto">
                      <li className="nav-item">
                          <a className="nav-link active" href="#">Home
                              <span className="visually-hidden">(current)</span>
                          </a>
                      </li>
                      <li className="nav-item">
                          <a className="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
                      </li>
                      <li className="nav-item">
                          <a className="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
                      </li>
                      <li className="nav-item">
                          <a className="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
                      </li>
                      <li className="nav-item dropdown">
                          <a className="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
                          <div className="dropdown-menu">
                              <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                              <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                              <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                              <div className="dropdown-divider"></div>
                              <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
                          </div>
                      </li>
                  </ul>
                  <form className="d-flex">
                      <input className="form-control me-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" />
                      <button className="btn btn-secondary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
                  </form>
              </div>
          </div>
      </nav>
    
  )
}

export default Header
```

Leftside.jsx

```
import React from 'react'

const Leftside = () => {
  return (
    <div>
        <div className ="accordion" id="accordionExample">
  <div className ="accordion-item">
    <h2 className ="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
      <button className ="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
        Accordion Item #1
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="collapseOne" className ="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div className ="accordion-body">
        <strong>This is the first item's accordion body.</strong> It is shown by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate className es that we use to style each element. These className es control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
        <strong>This is the first item's accordion body.</strong> It is shown by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate className es that we use to style each element. These className es control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
        <strong>This is the first item's accordion body.</strong> It is shown by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate className es that we use to style each element. These className es control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
      
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div className ="accordion-item">
    <h2 className ="accordion-header" id="headingTwo">
      <button className ="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
        Accordion Item #2
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="collapseTwo" className ="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div className ="accordion-body">
        <strong>This is the second item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate className es that we use to style each element. These className es control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div className ="accordion-item">
    <h2 className ="accordion-header" id="headingThree">
      <button className ="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
        Accordion Item #3
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="collapseThree" className ="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div className ="accordion-body">
        <strong>This is the third item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate className es that we use to style each element. These className es control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Leftside
```

middle.jsx

```
import React from 'react'

const Middle = () => {
  return (
    <div>
        <table className ="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Type</th>
      <th scope="col">Column heading</th>
      <th scope="col">Column heading</th>
      <th scope="col">Column heading</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr className ="table-active">
      <th scope="row">Active</th>
      <td>Column content</td>
      <td>Column content</td>
      <td>Column content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">Default</th>
      <td>Column content</td>
      <td>Column content</td>
      <td>Column content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr className ="table-primary">
      <th scope="row">Primary</th>
      <td>Column content</td>
      <td>Column content</td>
      <td>Column content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr className ="table-secondary">
      <th scope="row">Secondary</th>
      <td>Column content</td>
      <td>Column content</td>
      <td>Column content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr className ="table-success">
      <th scope="row">Success</th>
      <td>Column content</td>
      <td>Column content</td>
      <td>Column content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr className ="table-danger">
      <th scope="row">Danger</th>
      <td>Column content</td>
      <td>Column content</td>
      <td>Column content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr className ="table-warning">
      <th scope="row">Warning</th>
      <td>Column content</td>
      <td>Column content</td>
      <td>Column content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr className ="table-info">
      <th scope="row">Info</th>
      <td>Column content</td>
      <td>Column content</td>
      <td>Column content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr className ="table-light">
      <th scope="row">Light</th>
      <td>Column content</td>
      <td>Column content</td>
      <td>Column content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr className ="table-dark">
      <th scope="row">Dark</th>
      <td>Column content</td>
      <td>Column content</td>
      <td>Column content</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Middle
```

Rightside.jsx

```
import React from 'react'

const Rightside = () => {
  return (
    <div className='position-fixed' >
        
        <div  className="list-group ">
  <a href="#"  className="list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column align-items-start active">
    <div  className="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
      <h5  className="mb-1">List group item heading</h5>
      <small>3 days ago</small>
    </div>
    <p  className="mb-1">Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit.</p>
    <small>Donec id elit non mi porta.</small>
  </a>
  <a href="#"  className="list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column align-items-start">
    <div  className="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
      <h5  className="mb-1">List group item heading</h5>
      <small  className="text-muted">3 days ago</small>
    </div>
    <p  className="mb-1">Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit.</p>
    <small  className="text-muted">Donec id elit non mi porta.</small>
  </a>
</div>
       


    </div>
  )
}

export default Rightside
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.